# IIS Rewrite rule without specifying domain name

Tags: iis

I have two versions of a web site running on IIS 10. Dev version and Prod version. Each of them is running on a different domain.

When I make some changes on the Dev version, I would like to take exactly the same rules and copy-paste them to the Prod version without caring about changing the domain in the rules.

I have a rule like :

```
<rule name="Tontine - Accueil" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(SomeString/)+(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://www.DevDomain.com/somepage/{R:2}" />
</rule>
```

Is it possible to write a rewrite rule without specifiying the domain ? For example

- In Prod Domain : If I type www.proddomain.com/somestring, the rule will be rewrited to **https://www.proddomain.com/somepage/{R:2}**
- In Dev Domain : If I type www.devdomain.com/somestring, the rule will be rewrited to **https://www.devdomain.com/somepage/{R:2}**

I tryied the following but none of them worked :

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="/somepage/{R:2}" />    (The domain is not specified in the rule here)
or
<action type="Rewrite" url="./somepage/{R:2}" />
```

Is that possible please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use {HTTP_HOST} instead.

```
<rule name="Tontine - Accueil" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(SomeString/)+(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/somepage/{R:2}" />
</rule>
```